# Color coding points on spherical plot

Tags: plotting

I have a matrix with each element having two components. First component is an array of six elements, each of multiple of 1/6 but less than 1. Second component has two elements representing spherical coordinates (phi, theta). Following matrix shows an example with four elements.

```
{{{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 0}, {{1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 
  0, Pi/56}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, Pi/28}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, (3 Pi)/56}
```

Here, first element has the spherical coordinates (0, 0) with six elements being {2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6} and so on.
I want to plot this matrix in spherical coordinate system such that each point is colored according to the first element of the six element array...say red for 2/3, green for 1/3 blue for 1/6 etc. So {2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 0} should mean a red color dot at sphere at spherical coordinates (0, 0).

Will appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to plot... spherical coordinates require 3 coordinates, but you've only supplied two and it's not clear what the first element of each list should do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a constant coordinate we can just plot this in 2D I figure:

```
transf = Evaluate[CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {#, #3}]] &;

points = {
   {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 0}, {{1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 
    Pi/56}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, Pi/28}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 
    0, (3 Pi)/56}
   };

Map[{ColorData[98][6*#[[1]]], Point[transf @@ #]} &, Thread[#]] & /@ points //
  Graphics[{PointSize -> Large, #}] &
```

[image]

Alternately if you really want it in 3D:

```
transf = Evaluate[
    CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {#, #3, #2}]] &;

Map[{ColorData[98][6*#[[1]]], Point[transf @@ #]} &, Thread[#]] & /@ points //
  Graphics3D[{PointSize -> Large, #}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-.2, .2}, {-.1, .1}, All}] &
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
a = {{{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 0}, {{1/3, 1/3, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0,
     Pi/56}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, 
    Pi/28}, {{2/3, 0, 1/6, 0, 0, 1/6}, 0, (3 Pi)/56}};

R = 1;
Graphics3D[{
  Table[{Hue@a[[i, 1, 1]], PointSize[0.025], Point[R*{ 
       Sin[a[[i, 3]]] Cos[a[[i, 2]]],
       Sin[a[[i, 3]]] Sin[a[[i, 2]]],
       Cos[a[[i, 3]]]
       }
     ]}, {i, 1, Length@a}]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. something similar but on spherical surface.

Comment: As you see, I've used the Graphics3D for drawing. Therefore, you can add there any spheres or cuboids as you wish )